# Can anybody recognize and translate the phrase "El Rafael Pombo de Felipe Santiago Gutiérrez lo hice en hora y media … Clavdia [or Claudia]”?

Tags: traducción, definiciones

What's written on this picture? How you would translate it? I can recognize:

> El Rafael Pombo de Felipe Santiago Gutiérrez lo hice en hora y media …
>   Clavdia [or Claudia]

This is for description of the drawing on Wikipedia: [File:Rafael Pombo by Gutiérrez.jpg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rafael_Pombo_by_Guti%C3%A9rrez.jpg).

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The picture says: "El Rafael Pombo de Felipe Santiago Gutierrez lo hice en hora y media según Claudia". I'd translate as: "I did the Rafael Pombo by Felipe Santiago Gutiérrez in an hour and a half according to Claudia". [Rafael Pombo](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rafael_Pombo) is the model, Felipe Santiago Gutiérrez (a mexican painter from the XIX century) was the artist that draw the original and "me" is the one that made a copy in such a short time (in March 16, 2012).

Comment: Oh, this means that I can't use the drawing on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

It says:

> “El Rafael Pombo de Felipe Santiago Gutiérrez lo hice en hora y media según Claudia 16-3-12"

Translated:

> "The Rafael Pombo by Felipe Santiago Gutiérrez, I made it in an hour and a half according Claudia 3-16-14"

- "El Rafael..." is talking about the drawing, a drawing of Rafael.
- "...de Felipe Santiago..." is the author. "Made by..."
- "...lo hice en hora y media según Claudia..." is like saying "Claudia says that I made it in an hour and a half" but he's not sure about that.
- "16-3-12" is the date of the drawing March 16th, 2012.

Answer (score 2):

> El Rafael Pombo de Felipe Santiago Gutiérrez lo hice en hora y media según Claudia

Can be translated as:

> I made Rafael Pombo by Felipe Santiago Gutiérrez in one hour and a half according to Claudia.